# Windows Server 2008, shadow copies

Tags: windows, windows-server-2008, vss

I feel stupid for asking but I was always under the impression there was a way to make shadow copies of a file each time its saved. I have been looking around and can't find anything beyond scheduled times for shadow copies. A new client has a mess of a network, their old IT didn't set many things up properly and its been a major headache. The users have a tendency to  save over files instead of save as. The issue is there is never a shadow copy of these files unless its older than a day.

Comment: Yep, sounds like a prime use case for SharePoint.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Shadow copy is a point in time snapshot of the volume.  It is not a file versioning tool.  You can increase the frequency of your VSS snapshots, but you will never get one-snapshot per file write.

As for tools built-into Windows that permit file versioning.  You can get this to a certain degree with the Windows Sharepoint Services.